# Self hosted solution to frame content you want to share

Tags: html, self-hosted, sharing

Snip.ly lets you frame content you want to share, allowing you to add your own calls to action in the frame, and show 3rd party content inside the frame.

You need to enter the URL of the 3rd party content, and snip.ly creates a frameset on their site you can link to.

Does anyone know of a self-hosted version I can install on my own website which functions like snip.ly?

Comment: I was able to create a similar script but having problem fetching the meta data from the frameset

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, please?